# How can I make the output of a convnet an image with keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensor

I'm using 3d images as my input and my output...

```
model = Sequential()
#add model layers
model.add(Convolution3D(64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", input_shape=(240, 240, 155, 1)))
model.add(Convolution3D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

But instead of making the final layer a `Dense` with `softmax`, I want the output to be a 3D image of the same dimensions as the input.

What would I have to do to upsample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of upsampling - you can look in github for simple implementation of seg-net or U-net (or seg-u-net).